# What is the difference between an 'inference' and a 'prediction'?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Some say the two words 'inference' and 'predictions' can be used interchangeably. Personally, I think of an inference as the act that produces a prediction. Does anyone know if they are the same or do they mean something different? Is there some sort of historical English language explanation for the difference between the two?

Comment: What dictionaries did you check?

Answer (score 2):

An inference means that someone logically deduced from facts a conclusion. The conclusion may or may not be a prediction of what is to come, but what has already happened.

A prediction is a foretelling of a future event. It may or may not be an inference from facts at hand.

Answer (score 1):

The words carry distinct connotations, but both may be applicable in some circumstances. An inference is any conclusion drawn from evidence and reasoning, while a prediction is a forecast of what will happen in the future. Inferences need not be about the future, and predictions need not be based on evidence.

A prediction may be a type of inference if it is based on evidence and reasoning. For example, if I hear the garage door open and my dog start barking, I may both infer and predict that someone is about to walk through the door. I have made the inference that someone is home, and predicted they are about to come in.

But if I flip a coin, I may predict, but not infer, that it will land on heads, since my prediction is not based on any evidence. I can make a prediction but not an inference.

A prediction can also only be forward-looking. For example, if I note that the sky is cloudy and the grass is wet, I may infer, but not predict, that it rained recently, since it already happened. In this case, I can make an inference but not a prediction.

Comment: It is a pity this question is closed.  A correction is needed of a common misapprehension about the word  'infer' and its relationship to the word 'imply'.  Its relation to 'predict' is a different matter.  If I say today that it will rain tomorrow, that is a prediction, whether it turns out true or false.  If you go out with your raincoat on a sunny morning, I can 'infer' from your choice of outer wear that you think it might rain later.  I conclude that from the evidence of your behaviour.   We could say that your behaviour implies that you think it might rain.  CONTINUED

Comment: In logic there is a relationship between implication and inference.  To say "A implies B" means: 
"if A is true